# "Don't all shout at once" in German

Tags: english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

Suppose you are giving a talk, or some sort of presentation, and every now and then you ask a question, in order to give the audience an opportunity to take part in the discussion. Now, it often happens that, after asking a question, complete silence occurs in the room.

I find the sentence

> Don’t all shout at once.

a great way of breaking the silence and making the atmosphere slightly less formal, thus making people less stressed about asking a question.

What would be the right translation of this sentence to German? Alternatively, how would an equivalent statement in German sound?

Comment: I'm aiming for an effect, similar to that of the English version.

Comment: Damn, where is all this traffic coming from :)... @Takkat, can you see that somehow?

Comment: You have a fundamental problem here. Your English sentence is humorous. Germans are not. The most likely outcome is that they will take you literally and the silence will continue.

Comment: One word: Dontbeallshoutenatwonz.

Comment: @Mawg: You're forgetting that the German language is also used in Austria and Switzerland.

Comment: True. And I do find that Swiss, and, to some extent, Austrians do have some sense of humour (as do approximately  5 - 10% of Germans). Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You made my day @Omegacron !  And refuted Mawg's first claim  **if** you are German :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The most literal translation would be

> Ruft nicht alle auf einmal.

But I wouldn't use a verb probably. I don't know why but that would sound unnatural or at least it doesn't sound ironic or funny anymore. Maybe it's just too long. Either way.. the thing that came to mind first was

> Nicht alle auf einmal!

but there are other options, too, like

> Einer nach dem anderen!

Comment: I would definitely go for "Nicht alle auf einmal!".

Comment: @Emanuel "Nicht alle auf einmal!" sounds very good. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: "Bitte nicht alle durcheinander" is more colloquial flavour of the same phrase.

Answer (score 7):

If you aim at an ironic effect (not a literal translation), you can also say

> Nicht so zahlreich!

Comment: Yeah, this answer is more or less equivalent to Emanuel's suggestion *nicht alle auf einmal!* No real reason to favour one over the other imho.

Comment: Tbh, never heard or used that combination in a talk or similar (uni, industry, conferences).

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu I heard this expression quite often in Austrian educational institutions, in exactly the same context as described by the author of the question.

Comment: That sounds weird to my northern ears.

Answer (score 2):

> Rufen Sie nicht alle durcheinander!
>
> Ruft nicht alle durcheinander!

In the situation you are describing, I would consider talking to be a more appropriate description than shouting, and I would consider the use of *please* almost necessary. The same applies to the German sentence, leading to:

> Reden Sie bitte nicht alle durcheinander!
>
> Bitte reden Sie nicht alle durcheinander!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

> Nur nicht drängeln

or

> Bitte nicht drängeln

Answer (score 1):

You may also say "Ist ja wie auf einer Beerdigung hier." which is a sloppy phrase for the mood/silence is like being on a funeral where there shouldn't be.